# ¿Existe diferencia entre trabajar con distribución a crear jobs?

Tags: sql-server

Esta es una consulta un poco más teórica y no sé si corresponde a esta sección. He estado buscando información con respecto a esto pero encuentro más cosas de cómo se genera una distribución y los tipos que hay.

El caso es que donde estoy trabajando para distribuir información a unos pc que tenemos usamos distribución pero a veces esta se pega o no trabaja (yo lo atribuyo a que las características que tiene el pc que manda no es un servidor como tal).

Y mi jefe quiere usar Jobs, que tenga consultas de insert, update y delete cuando corresponda pero encuentro que esto es demasiado trabajo y va a tomar demasiado tiempo implementar algo así.

En terminos de operación a nivel de base de datos, existe alguna diferencia en trabajar una distribución como tal y "migrarla" para usar Jobs? Y en consumo de recursos, costo de un select o etc varía?

Si alguien me puede guiar o darme algún link en donde pueda yo estudiar esto se los agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Muchas Gracias.